# Which Words Should I Stress?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, american-accent, word-stress, phonetics

here are four sentences. I mark the words that I believe are stressed with bold.

1. I'll **call** you **back**.
2. I'll **call** you **back** in a **min**ute.
3. I'll **call** you **back** in a few **min**utes.
4. I'll **call** you **back** as soon as I **can**

Did I apply the stress correctly? The last content word gets the most stress.Right? If yes, my question is this: is it necessary to apply some stress to the verb "call" or just stress the last content words? The verb is also a content word.

Comment: This can get pretty subjective and is based on how you're trying to say it. For 4, I'd probably stress **soon**.

Comment: Yes, it's true that any word can be stressed to give it emphasis, there is a default unemphatic accent however.I recorded it: https://clyp.it/a5rmhgzq In the first one I stressed both "call" and "back". In the second one I only stressed "back".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the preposition in a phrasal verb has no noun complement afterwards it is usually stressed:

- **Take** off the **jum**per
- **Take** the **jum**per **off**
- **Take** **off**

For this reason all the instances of *back* in the Original Poster's example will probably be stressed. As the Original Poster has indicated lexical verbs will usually also take stress, but auxiliaries *usually* won't unless in a negative contraction. An exception to this is when they occur at the end of the sentence, when they will often be stressed. This is why *can* is stressed in sentence (4). Adverbs usually take stress, so the adverb *soon* is likely to be stressed. The quantifiers *many* and *few* also usually take stress too. Because of this we would expect the following stress patterns:

1. I'll **call** you **back**.
2. I'll **call** you **back** in a **min**ute.
3. I'll **call** you **back** in a **few** **min**utes.
4. I'll **call** you **back** as **soon** as I **can**